# Debugging through VBA steps into a different function

Tags: excel, vba

When I have a workbook with VBA code that includes a custom function, the debugger randomly steps into the function mid-code.

This happens both when I have UDF in .xlam files, and custom functions in local macros. It wouldn't be an issue if it only loops through the function once but it seems to loop infinitely, which makes debugging impossible.

e.g. here is one which gave me the issue today:

```
Sub checkdailytotal()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long, n As Long
Dim filepath As String, filedate As String, filename As String, filename2 As String, _
  filename3 As String, filetoopen As String
Dim totalunit As Double
Dim checkcount As Range

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim rg As Range, rg2 As Range, reg As Range, unitcol As Range, daterow As Range
Dim regcheck As Range, regfind As Range
Dim regnum As String, nofile As String, nofind As String, nomatch As String, _
  totalmatch As String
Dim sharec As Double, sharediff As Double, totalshare As Double
Dim check As Range

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

filepath = "C:\Username\filepath\"
On Error Resume Next
With Sheet3
    Set checkcount = .Range("B2")
    .Range("A3:E50").Clear 'This is where the function got called
End With

With Sheet2
    i = WorksheetFunction.Count(.Range("A:A"))
    Set reg = .Range("A2", .Cells(2, .Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column))
    Set unitcol = .Range("C2", .Cells(.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row, "C"))
    For j = 1 To i 'change this to i, just testing
        Set daterow = .Range("A2").Offset(j, 0)
        checkcount.Offset(j, -1).Value = j
        filedate = Format(.Range("A2").Offset(j, 0).Value, "YYYYMMDD")
        filename = filepath & "XYZ File name" & filedate & ".xlsx"
        filename2 = filepath & "XYZ file name" & _
          Format(.Range("A2").Offset(j, 0).Value, "DD.MM.YYYY") & ".xlsx"
        filename3 = filepath & filedate & ".xlsx"
        If Len(Dir(filename)) = 0 Then
            If Len(Dir(filename2)) = 0 Then
                If Len(Dir(filename3)) = 0 Then
                    nofile = "No File"
                Else
                    filetoopen = filename3
                End If
            Else
                filetoopen = filename2
            End If
        Else
            filetoopen = filename
        End If
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filetoopen, Password:="password")
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
        With ws
            nofind = ""
            nomatch = ""
            Set regcheck = .Range("H2")
            n = .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row - 2
            For k = 1 To n
                regnum = regcheck.Offset(k, 0).Value
                Set regfind = reg.Find(regnum, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If regfind Is Nothing Then
                    nofind = nofind & " " & regfind
                Else
                    'find the sharecount in monthly file
                    sharec = regfind.Offset(j, 0).Value

                    sharediff = regcheck.Offset(k, 4).Value - sharec
                    If Abs(Round(sharediff, 1)) > 0 Then
                        nomatch = nomatch & " " & regfind & " " & sharediff
                    End If
                End If
            Next k
            wb.Close False
            totalshare = regcheck.Offset(j + 1, 4).Value
            totalmatch = Abs(Round(totalshare - unitcol.Value, 1))
            Call totalcheck(daterow.Value, nofile, totalmatch, nofind, nomatch)
            nofile = ""
        End With
    Next j
End With

MsgBox "Check complete"
Application.Goto Sheet3.Range("A1")

End Sub


Sub totalcheck(datech As Double, nofilepath As String, totalshare As String, _
  regfind As String, regmatch As String)
Dim check As Range
Dim m As Long

With Sheet3
    Set check = .Range("B2")
    m = WorksheetFunction.Count(.Range("A:A"))
    Set check = check.Offset(m, 0)
    With check
        With .Offset(0, 0)
            .Value = datech
            .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        End With
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = nofilepath
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = totalshare
        .Offset(0, 3).Value = regfind
        .Offset(0, 4).Value = regmatch
    End With
End With

End Sub


Function tplus1(todaydt As Date)

Dim holidays As Range
Dim wk As Long, wk2 As Long, wk3 As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim t1 As Date

wk = WorksheetFunction.Weekday(todaydt, 2) 'mon=1, sun=7
If wk > 5 Then
    tplus1 = "Weekend"
    Exit Function
End If

If wk < 5 Then 'mon-thurs
    t1 = todaydt + 1
Else 'friday
    t1 = todaydt + 3
End If

With Sheet4
    Set holidays = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row, "A"))
End With

i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(holidays, t1)
wk2 = WorksheetFunction.Weekday(t1, 2) 'mon=1, sun=7

If i = 0 Then
    tplus1 = t1
    Exit Function
End If

If i > 0 Then
    Do Until i = 0
        If wk2 < 5 Then
            t1 = t1 + 1
            i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(holidays, t1)
        ElseIf wk2 = 5 Then
            t1 = t1 + 3
            i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(holidays, t1)
        ElseIf wk2 = 6 Then
            t1 = t1 + 2
            i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(holidays, t1)
        ElseIf wk2 = 7 Then
            t1 = t1 + 1
            i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(holidays, t1)
        End If
    wk2 = WorksheetFunction.Weekday(t1, 2)
    Loop
End If
tplus1 = t1

End Function
```

Comment: If you're referencing custom functions in cells, the debugger will step through that code when the cell recalculates. To avoid this, turn calculations to Manual, instead of Automatic (Formulas tab, Calculation Options).

Comment: I didn't realize! I'll just add that line. Thank you!

Comment: And to add to @JoshEller's comment, the function will be called *for each cell that uses the formula*!

Comment: When it steps into the UDF, use the Step Out and you should have all of that UDF calculated for all cells that use it and be put back to the next line of code outside of the UDF.